# run the WRF model using ERA5

Tags: atmosphere-modelling, wrf, era, wrf-chem

I want to run wrf chem with ERA 5. I followed this post https://dreambooker.site/2018/04/20/Initializing-the-WRF-model-with-ERA5/. Everything works fine unless I add surface pressure to surface data list(SP or 134.128). metgrid.exe threw out

```
Processing domain 1 of 1
 Processing 2015-06-01_00
    FILE
    PRES
ERROR: Error in ext_pkg_write_field
application called MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0) - process 0
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the right Vtable? That error message is saying that the soil temperature variable is missing/couldn't be read.

Comment: This error is misleading since it also occures when metgrid.exe is also successful. I would remove from my question. I still have problem to involve surface pressure in surface data.